# Why can't unregistered users post on meta?

Tags: support, login, per-site-meta, unregistered-users

A [particular user](https://superuser.com/users/67387/randolf-richardson) was trying to [post a problem that he had about migration of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81974/provide-feedback-that-a-question-was-migrated-while-posting-an-answer), and it would seem that he is not able to login. Why is this so?

The user in question has amassed closed to 1k in rep, so I would assume that he should be able to post to meta, instead - while trying to submit a question - he gets an error:

> I just tried to submit a big one in "meta" about this problem, but it tells me that I have to be logged in. I thought I was logged in (my name is at the top and I can modify my profile, etc.), but for some reason the system thinks I'm not logged in. I

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be a registered user to participate on per-site metas.

This is not a bug.

Tell that user to click the register link at the top of every page we serve them, if they want the privilege to

- upvote (unregistered users CANNOT vote, but can accrue most other privileges)
- post on the per-site meta

Comment: I have told @RandolfRichardson to register, apparently he's lost his openID password and is waiting for the reset mail, and doesn't want to create accounts elsewhere.