# Provide feedback that a question was migrated while posting an answer

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, migration

I'm posting this on behalf of [Randolf Richardson](https://superuser.com/users/67387/randolf-richardson) since [he cannot login to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81972/why-cant-unregistered-users-post-on-meta)

---

> I was [answering a question](https://superuser.com/questions/254119/is-it-possible-to-share-the-revenue-between-two-accounts) this
>   evening, and then the buttons got
>   deactivated (for submitting my answer
>   as well as for submitting comments),
>   so I saved my answer in the clipboard
>   and went back to the list of questions
>   and selected the same question which
>   nobody had answered yet.  Once again I
>   could post an answer, but the buttons
>   were greyed out (this time before I
>   could enter any text).
>
> I later found out that the question
>   had been migrated.
>
> Users put a lot of effort and are
>   contributing their time for free to
>   make this a helpful environment.  If
>   answers are going to be discarded
>   because a question was migrated, then
>   I believe this is a design flaw
>   because that can result in the loss of
>   good quality answers.
>
> I believe the system should do one of
>   the following:
>
> 1. Submit the answer anyway, but automatically migrate it as well
> 2. Save the answer for whoever migrated the question to decide if the
>      answer should be migrated or if the
>      question should be de-migrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: we *DO* provide feedback on migrations to people answering via topbar notification

[image]

The unsubmitted answer would still be saved as a draft, since we auto-save drafts for questions and answers every 45 seconds.

However, I'm not 100% sure the draft would *be visible* when you came back to that answer. Normally it would be, but since we suppress the answer editing area on migrated / closed / otherwise functionally unanswerable questions.. might not be in that case.

Comment: I believe the answer would be visible if you went to another question, if my understanding of how the draft function works is correct. However, that doesn't seem entirely user-friendly to me. Perhaps <s>unnecessarily complex</s>more obvious UI is required.

Comment: @hello no, the draft is only visible on the question it was saved on, and there is only one per user per site. So the very next time you start typing in an answer box and wait 45 seconds, that new answer draft will overwrite the old one.